# PowerShell - fast remove a directory with 10,000+ files

Tags: performance, beginner, file-system, powershell

I am sick of File Explorer's super slow deletion speed, so I tried to write a PowerShell script to make deletion faster, and while it does its job, its speed isn't as high as what I intended it to be.

I have written this:

```
Function Fast-Delete {
    Param(
    [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)] [String]$Directory0
    )
    Write-Warning "This Process Will Delete Everything In The Target Directory: $Directory0, Do You Want To Confirm Deletion?" -Warningaction Inquire
    $Directory=$Directory0
    While ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory0 -Depth 0 -Force).Count -Ne 0) {
    If ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Directory -Force -Depth 0).Count -Ne 0) {
    $Directory=(Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Directory -Force -Depth 0).Fullname | Select-Object -Index 0
    }
    If ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Force).Count -Ne 0) {
    (Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Recurse -Force).Fullname | Foreach {Remove-Item -Path $_}
    }
    $Directory1=$Directory
    $Directory=$Directory | Split-Path -Parent
    Remove-Item -Path $Directory1
    }
    Remove-Item -Path $Directory0
}
```

It is significantly faster than explorer, but still isn't ideal, I have tested it, I used it to delete 208,000 files in 1,000 folders , and the folders disappear at speed of 1 per second, so it's about 208 files/s, now the next challenge should be parallelization, But this is currently really way above me, but it shouldn't be too hard, I am just not experienced enough.

Update2

I have managed to make it run in parallel with this script:

```
function Parallel-Delete {
    param(
    [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [array]$filelist,
    [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [int]$number
    )
    0..($filelist.count-1) | Where-Object {$_ % 16 -eq $number} | foreach {Remove-Item -Path $filelist[$_]}
}

Function Fast-Delete {
    Param(
    [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)] [String]$Directory0
    )
    Write-Warning "This Process Will Delete Everything In The Target Directory:  $Directory0, Do You Want To Confirm Deletion?" -Warningaction Inquire
    $Directory=$Directory0
    While ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory0 -Depth 0 -Force).Count -Ne 0) {
        If ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Directory -Force -Depth 0).Count -Ne 0) {
            $Directory=(Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Directory -Force -Depth 0).Fullname | Select-Object -Index 0
        }
        If ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Force).Count -Ne 0) {
            If ((Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Force).Count -Ge 128) {
                [array]$filelist=(Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Force).Fullname
                0..15 | foreach-object {Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Parallel-Delete $filelist $_}}
                } else {
                (Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -File -Force).Fullname | Foreach {Remove-Item -Path $_}
            }
        }
        $Directory1=$Directory
        $Directory=$Directory | Split-Path -Parent
        Remove-Item -Path $Directory1
        }
    Remove-Item -Path $Directory0 -erroraction silentlycontinue
}
$Directory0=Read-Host "Please input target directory to be deleted"
Fast-Delete $Directory0
```

But it still isn't ideal, it isn't 15 times faster as expected, what did I miss?

Edit: simplified the creation of parallel processes.

Comment: the fastest way to delete an entire dir tree is to use robocopy. you mirror a blank "source" dir to the one you want removed ... and the "destination" gets emptied _quickly_. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, in fact I wanted to write a new script, not to use existing things, and the method you mentioned sounds like a bug...

Comment: i understand your desire. [*grin*] as for a bug ... it is exactly what the options mean - mirror empty source to full destination gives empty source and empty destination. so ... have fun playing with a script ...but PoSh will always be slower than any well written utility.

Comment: And I have tried Start-Job, but they just hang in place, they are not working so I used stop-job to terminate them... And still I can't pass to variables to new powershell process started by start-process...

Comment: i would narrow your problems to specifics ... and open a Question for each of them. the `pass variable to start-process` question has been answered here OR in stackoverflow many times.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Replace all `where-object` with `foreach-object` and use `If()` conditions instead. Put `process { }` wrap in all your `foreach-object` and also in all `invoke-command` within your script. E.g. `0..($filelist.count-1) | % { Process { If ($_ % 16 -eq $number) { Remove-Item -Path $filelist[$_] } } }` and `0..15 | % { Process { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Process { Parallel-Delete $filelist $_ }}}}` for starters... Just start incorporating that way and then measure to test the speed differences. I always start with those simple techniques for PS processing speed 101.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Yes, it's me from the other sister site with an old handle name or whatever it is called. Look at my profile and click on the SU community from there and you'll see. I don't use the same avatar or moniker on each of the communities always so I mix and match like a bucket of chicken from KFC.

Comment: why you dont remove the dire complete and recreate him after ?

Comment: So... I've been doing some testing, as I'm in a similar boat.  A 2 GB folder, containing 10,000 items, is stored on a network drive (I had ~200 when I started removing directories).  An individual directory click-delete via explorer has been deleting 3.1 files/sec (includes analyze and deletiion time); a single line `remove-item` I average 2.4 files/sec; a power shell script for `robocopy /purge` with a blank directory averages 2.4 files/sec (this still analyzes each individual file in the parent directory)... i am about to try `robocopy /mir` to see if it's any faster.

Comment: I have found the best success thusfar individually deleting files via explorer (typically 10 at a time), where I drop to roughly the same delete speed as individual directory removal via power shell.  The in-parallel deletion has given me a small/minimal drop at moving from 1 directories to 5 directories, and an almost 1 file/sec drop at 10, where each deleted file is ~10k files inside of a 2 GB directory.

Comment: I finished removing all of my back-up directories using HacknSlash's code, changing from `/purge` to `/mir`.  That change went from ~2.4 files/sec to ~5.5 files/sec (n=100).  It was the fastest method of those I tried.  Your speed may be drastically different as the only way to access this network drive is via VPN, so that connection was a limiting factor, which I feel allowed a more full picture of the differences in speed to execute each method.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in a comment from @Lee_Daily, reinventing the wheel from an interpreted language like PowerShell will be slower than a native implementation. If your primary concern is speed, use the correct tool for the job. We have a native implementation in [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

It has an option `/mir`

> Mirrors a directory tree (equivalent to /e plus /purge). Using this option with the /e option and a destination directory, overwrites the destination directory security settings.

Below is the `robocopy` purge method using your framework:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)] [String]$Directory
)

Function Fast-Delete {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)] [String]$Directory
    )

    Write-Warning "This Process Will Delete Everything In The Target Directory:  $Directory, Do You Want To Confirm Deletion?" -Warningaction Inquire

    $emptyDir = GetRandomTempPath
    mkdir $emptyDir

    robocopy $emptyDir $Directory /mir

    Remove-Item -Path $Directory -erroraction silentlycontinue
    Remove-Item -Path $emptyDir -erroraction silentlycontinue
}

Function GetRandomTempPath {
    Do {
        $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()
    } While (Test-Path $fullPath);

    Return $fullPath;
} 

Fast-Delete $Directory
```

Save as: `Fast-Delete.ps1`

**Comparison of delete methods** (2 GB, 10,000 files in directory):

- remove-item: 2.4 files/sec average (n=10)
- /purge : 2.4 files/sec average (n=3)
- /purge /mt: 2.5 files/sec average (n=3)
- explorer-based click-delete: 3.1 files/sec (n=30)
- /mir: 5.5 files/sec (n = 100)

Comment: I don't use PowerShell myself (I'm more of a POSIX shell and Bash user), but it looks to my untrained eye that your suggested code assumes that there's no existing non-empty `$TEMP/uniqueemptydirname`, without checking.  Is there no `mktemp` available from this shell?  Also, I'd guess that the most useful amount of parallelism would depend more on the storage throughput than on the number of CPU threads here.

Comment: You are 100% correct in that assumption. I added a function for `GetRandomTempPath` in PowerShell. It doesn't come with a method like this that I could find.

Answer (score 3):

The `foreach-object` is not run in parallel by default.
You need specify the `-Parallel` parameter. And the version of Powershell need be greater than 7.0

See [Official Blob](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) and [Official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7)